# Hide overflow on a specific background

Tags: css, svg

I'm not really sure if the title makes sense, but I can't find a way to explain shortly what the problem is without an image.
This is the scenario:

[image]

All the red you see is an svg element which is filled with red and has a transparent background in order to see the underlying orange lines. It's a section separator which has this "wave" style that separates the upper section (red) from the next one (white).
On the upper section, I have some elements with orange dotted borders (the 5 ones you see on the right side), which are absolute positioned at the bottom of the red section. In fact, you see the borders end at the end of the svg, but obviously, the svg is a rectangle and they overflow on the white space. The svg is positioned normally, at the end (part of) the red section.

I need those borders to stop at the end of the red part of the svg, but I just can't. I thought about reversing the svg (making the white part the actual svg and making the background transparent on the red section) but in that way I wouldn't see the orange lines at the bottom, they'd be covered by the white svg. They're in the background of the next section so they have to stay in the background.

Also I can't clip anything because the svg is always at 100% width, so modifying the width of the monitor would cause the orange vertical lines to fall on different positions on the svg.

How could I handle this scenario? Thanks!

PS. I added a minimal jsfiddle to reproduce the scenario, I made the overall background grey in stead of white so that you can see where the svg ends: https://jsfiddle.net/bydcxr2b/

```
<section class="upper">

  <section class="upper-inner"></section>

  <div class="items">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>


  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px"
   width="100%" viewBox="0 0 1200 110" xml:space="preserve">
    <path fill="red" d="M1200,110L765.285,95.51c-52.554-11.983-114.671-36.865-143.727-37.924 c-37.374-1.362-56.742,16.644-94.115,15.281c-37.375-1.362-54.699-39.417-92.073-40.779c-37.374-1.362-56.742,16.644-94.115,15.281
    c-37.374-1.362-36.012-38.736-92.072-40.779c-49.454-1.803-42.871,56.671-79.112,69.079L0,70V0h1200V110z"/>
  </svg>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.upper {
  position: relative;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.upper-inner {
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.items {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 100px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px dotted orange;
  margin: 0 20px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find it necessary. I added a fiddle now.

Comment: and i suppose the whole thing need to responsive ?

Comment: Well there's nothing really "responsive", let's say it's responsive because the wave svg is always 100% with so it adapts to the window, the elements with the dotted border are position absolute at bottom right of the section.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/SirExotic/bydcxr2b/1/)

I added a `height: 100%;` to *.items* and a `height: auto;` to *.upper* so that the individual *.items* can have a 100% height relative to their parent (*.items*) and the height of *.items* is relative to the height (`auto`) of its own parent (*.upper*).

```css
.upper {
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.upper-inner {
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.items {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100px;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px dotted black;
  margin: 0 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="upper">
  <div class="upper-inner"></div>

  <div class="items">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>

  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 1200 110" xml:space="preserve">
      <path fill="red" d="M1200,110L765.285,95.51c-52.554-11.983-114.671-36.865-143.727-37.924 c-37.374-1.362-56.742,16.644-94.115,15.281c-37.375-1.362-54.699-39.417-92.073-40.779c-37.374-1.362-56.742,16.644-94.115,15.281
        c-37.374-1.362-36.012-38.736-92.072-40.779c-49.454-1.803-42.871,56.671-79.112,69.079L0,70V0h1200V110z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Hummm nope that’s not what I need, I have no problem with the position of the items, i just need their borders to end in the red part of the svg (hide Them on the grey part)

Comment: Ah! I thought they should end at the bottom of the grey background. I'll get on it.

Comment: Just to clarify, [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/WqATNyQ.png) is your goal, correct?

Comment: This is all I could come up with... [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/SirExotic/bydcxr2b/2/). As I see it I think you'll have to decide between either the lines or the spirals.

Comment: I went away for a few hours to clear my mind (I guess it was the only option :D) and maybe I found a solution, inverting the svg as you did and making him white, but part of the second section with a negative margin that drags it at the top, on the red part. That way working with z-indexes on the lines should be easy. I'll try tomorrow and if it works I'll post the answer :)

Comment: If you take a look at the Fiddle in my last comment, that's exactly what I tried to do, but it is impossible with z-index because of how the elements are nested. :/